# Why are these steps algebraically correct?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, power-series

Consider the first few steps for representing the function $f(x) = \ln{\left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)}$ as a power series:
$$
f(x) = \ln{\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)}
= \ln{ \left( 1 + x \right) } - \ln{ \left( 1 - x \right) }
= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + x} + \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 - x}
$$

I incorrectly subtracted the values of these integrals when attempting to represent this function as a power series, which led to the following question:

- What is the algebraic reason for equating the difference of two logarithmic functions to the sum of their representations as integrals?

Comment: Integrate the right hand side - because the $-x$ in the second the integral will come out as $-\ln|1-x|$

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for talking through it.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-x} = \color{red}{-}\ln(1-x)$$

That's why you need to ADD the integral.